# React Native Android app does not load JS bundle properly

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I have a problem with the bundling of JS in my RN 0.63.3 app when building for Android.

I have the variants `release`, `debug`, `dev` and `alphaRelease`. `debug` works as expected and connects to the bundle server, but the other ones cause a crash/white screen when running the app.

But if I run a `./gradlew assembleAlphaRelease` and install the app, it crashes, telling me that the file `app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle` cannot be found. (It's the same with `release` and `dev`). I can see that it runs the `bundleJsAndAssets` step though.

When I search for the `index.android.bundle` after building, I can see these files which all have the same content, but none of them are found by the running app.

```
./app/build/generated/assets/react/alphaRelease/index.android.bundle
./app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/alphaRelease/out/index.android.bundle
./app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/alphaRelease/mergeAlphaReleaseAssets/out/index.android.bundle
./app/build/intermediates/assets/alphaRelease/index.android.bundle
```

If I run command below, there will be an `index.android.bundle` at the right location, and the app will work as expected after rebuilding.

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
```

I guess that my app should load the JS from the file in `./app/build/generated/assets/react/alphaRelease/index.android.bundle`?

It can already load the assets without problems, from `./app/build/generated/res/react/alphaRelease/drawable*`, but not the JS bundle.

I've tried various settings in the `project.ext.react` section of `build.gradle` but nothing seems to help. It acts the same if I set `jsBundleDirAlphaRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/alphaRelease",` etc.

So: How can I make the app load the JS bundle from one of the locations where it exists, so I don't have to manually generate this file every time?